# Phonegap sqlite database, insert chinese characters

Tags: database, sqlite, utf-8, cordova, chinese-locale

When I use Phonegap db interface to insert chinese characters, it just doesn't work, is there a way to fix it on both IOS and android platform.

Comment: It's easy: just fix the bugs in your code. (Which you have not shown.)

Comment: It seems work on device but not emulator, must look more into this.